# Real-sounding male to female realtime voice changer

Tags: voice

I'd like to prank some people on Discord and video game in game voice chat. Google gives me recommendations which arent very good - they make me sound like an alien or something weird. The ones that I've tried are clown fish and voicemod. Is there any software which is better?